# Android Screen is not moving up while entering text in EditText

Tags: android

Already i used adjust pan in manifest file--i am using five edit text field--like register form..if i enter text in edit text-- after screen will move up--but for me screen not moving--
anyone guide me--

Comment: moving means you want toscroll your page?

Comment: wrap your `EditTexts` in `ScrollView`

Comment: add these statement in edittext . android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: Add this in manifest **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"**

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much attach the following in your manifest:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

To get a better understanding see link below:

http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html#Respond

Answer (score 0):

try this line in your manifest file inside activity tag, it may help

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```